# Javascript Date object different depending on format: yyyy-mm-dd vs mm-dd-yyyy

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, formatting, date-formatting

Another JavaScript Date conundrum...

I get two completely different Date objects depending on the format I pass to the Date constructor (Date.parse() also produces different results).

**Example:**

**new Date('04-27-2016');** => Wed Apr 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

**Date.parse('04-27-2016');** => 1461733200000

vs

**new Date('2016-04-27');**  Apr 26 2016 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

**Date.parse('04-27-2016');** => 1461715200000

I can easily work around this situation in my code, but I would like an explanation as to why/how this is doing what it does.

Comment: The first date example (which doesn't work on my system with locale = Canada) is assumed to be local time.  The second example uses ISO8601 format so it's assumed to be UTC time. [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: exactly, an assumption

Answer (score 1):

The ISO format you use in the second example has UTC as its default timezone. It's described [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Differences_in_assumed_time_zone). If you want the correct behaviour for this format, you have to add the information about timezone: `new Date('2016-04-27 GMT-0500');` or you have to also specify the time: `new Date('2016-04-27 00:00:00');`

In my opinion it's better not to use the built-in parser and use some library instead. For example [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is great.